# how to reduce libskiasharp.so size?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skia, skiasharp

I try to use skiasharp to develop xamarin forms app, then I found the apk file is too big in android platform.
I take a look at the apk file and it looks like the libSkiaSharp.so is too big.
Is there any way to reduce the size of libSkiaSharp.so???
Thanks very much!

Comment: `libSkiaSharp.so` is around 12MB and it is already a "stripped" library, without removing native features and creating a new C# wrapper, there is nothing else that can reduce its size...

Comment: What do you mean 'Too big"? What size is acceptable to you? Have you tried changing linking settings?

Comment: I am looking at this all the time, and here is an issue to track all progress: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/174

Comment: On that issue, any feedback or suggestions, or even a PR will be more than awesome!

Answer (score 1):

This has been a hot topic and I think we have solved most (if not all) of our size problems. We have managed to reduce the size of each platform architecture to ~5MB.

Hopefully this is small enough for most apps. Please let me know your views on this.

https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/174